# Does a GCP stateful Managed Instance Group checkpoint restore machine state or just disk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm just getting into setting up a feature we were originally doing with local VMs, now through Google Cloud Platform and some of the features and terminology are confusing me.

I need to launch a batch operations where multiple VMs launch and then interact with each-other via RESTful APIs for perhaps 10 minutes before shutting down. We're using preemptable spot VMs to save on cost, so failure-cases are highly relevant and potentially frequent.

We're looking at [stateful Managed Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs#what_makes_a_mig_stateful) for our use-case:

> Stateful MIGs are intended for applications with stateful data or
> configuration, such as:
>
> ...
>
> **Batch workloads with checkpointing.** With this configuration, you can
> preserve checkpointed results of long-running computation in
> anticipation of workload or VM failure or instance preemption.
> Stateful MIGs can recreate a failed machine, while preserving its data
> disk, so that your computation can continue from the last checkpoint.

The nature of our use-case is such that any machine being preempted means the entire batch needs to restart, which seems trivial to accomplish with GCP Compute Engine API. The issue I'm having is what GCP's documentation means when it talks about the notion of "checkpoints" and "snapshots" because it keeps referring to things as "disk state", which to me means *not* memory / full machine state.

To reiterate from the documentation cited above:

> Stateful MIGs can recreate a failed machine, while **preserving its data disk**, so that your computation can continue from the last checkpoint.

If *just* the **disk** is snapshotted / checkpointed, that means only progress captured on disk, not in memory, will be restored, right? The VMs will still have to undergo the boot / startup process, and any other post-boot initialization required to get the applications running? It's not like a Docker image where I can just save an image and trivially start from an exact machine state?

Or by some chance does the terminology here somehow actually mean the full machine state is in fact preserved, like a traditional VM snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify your doubts about the stateful MIG; in general, when you deploy a Managed instance Group, this will try to recreate your instance if a VM crashes or if a managed instance stops running. And, if this change of state was not initiated by the MIG, then the MIG automatically recreates that instance based on the configuration that you specified to your VM at the moment of creating your MIG, or will try to recreate the instance based on an instance template created for you before to create your MIG. So, based on this, the Stateful MIG preserves each instance’s unique state (instance name, attached persistent disks, and metadata) on machine restart, recreation, auto-healing, and update events.
Regarding the snapshots and the disk state, the stateful MIG takes the configure disk that is defined in the instance template to become stateful for the instance  (  by adding those disks to the per-instance configuration) or to become stateless (by removing those disks from the per-instance configuration). So, you can deploy a stateful disk in your MIG in order to  preserve the data on disks, even in the event of VM recreation state of the disk. You can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/create-mig-with-basic-stateful-disks#create_a_mig_with_stateful_disks) to deploy stateful disks in your MIG. It is also recommended to deploy a stateful persistent [disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/configuring-stateful-disks-in-migs) and then you can configure [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots) from this disk if you need it.